# Quick simple PHP issue - accessing variable in function

Tags: php

Not used PHP for quite a while, jumped back in and was hit by an error that doesn't make sense to me, this code:

```
$errorCount = 0;
$errorList = array();

function getParam($paramId){
    if (isset($_GET[$paramId])){
        $id = $_GET[$paramId];
    } else {
         $errorList[] = (string)$paramId;
         $errorCount++;
    };
};


getParam("id");
```

The error that pops up is:
Undefined variable: errorCount

I can't see why that would fail, but $errorList doesn't - I'm sure it's something silly.

Comment: You're misunderstanding variable scope in php http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: `$errorCount` and `$errorList` are both undefined inside `getParam`.  `$errorList[]` automatically creates the variable (and makes it an array) if it doesn't exist.  That's why `$errorList` "works" and `$errorCount` doesn't.

Comment: This is what happens when you jump off JS to PHP - I assumed global was automatically set by being outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variable scope issue. The variable isn't available inside the function's scope, so it'll just display the error message.

Consider the following case:

```
$hello = 'hello';
function test() {
    echo $hello;
}
test();
```

[**See it live!**](https://eval.in/50687)

The variable `$hello` is defined in the code, but when you try to execute the above code, you'll get an error saying `Undefined variable: hello`.

If you want your variables to be accessible inside the function, pass them as parameters, like so:

```
$hello = 'hello';
function test($hello) {
    echo $hello;
}
test($hello);
```

[**See it live!**](https://eval.in/50685)

---

Now, to fix your actual issue, you can pass `$errorCount` as [reference](http://php.net/reference):

```
$errorCount = 0;
$errorList = array();

function getParam($paramId, & $errorCount){
    if (isset($_GET[$paramId])){
        $id = $_GET[$paramId];
    } else {
         $errorList[] = (string)$paramId;
         $errorCount++;
    };
};
```

An alternative solution would be to use [`global`](http://php.net/global) variables, but this isn't a *very* good practice, in my opinion, and should be avoided if possible. You may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why) post to understand why.

Refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your variables are not defined in the scope of your function. You have a few options. 1 option is to declare those variables global. Or you can create a class.

```
function getParam($paramId){
  global $errorList;
  global $errorCount;
    if (isset($_GET[$paramId])){
        $id = $_GET[$paramId];
    } else {
         $errorList[] = (string)$paramId;
         $errorCount++;
    };
};
```

You can also pass the variables in by reference:

For example:

```
$my_variable = array();
$my_variable_ct = 0;


function fn($arg1, $my_var, $my_var_count) {
   // do everything here
}

fn("Hello", &$my_variable, &$my_variable_ct);
```

Comment: It can also be written as `global $errorList, $errorCount`. Note that `global` variables are not always seen in a good light with most programmers (but it doesn't matter much as PHP runs very short sessions).

Answer (score 0):

Normal variables that are defined outside the functions, are not accessible by default. To reach them, we should simply use `global $var1, $var2;` to access their value like this:

```
$errorCount = 0;
$errorList = array();

function getParam($paramId){

    global $errorList, $errorCount;

    if (isset($_GET[$paramId])){
        $id = $_GET[$paramId];
    } else {
         $errorList[] = (string)$paramId;
         $errorCount++;
    };
};


getParam("id");
```